# Formatting File Names re' \addchap input

Tags: formatting

I have a list of \addchap commands, each of which calls a file that is named as e.g. C001 My File.tex. The title contains capitalised words and a single space separating them.

When the Main File.tex is compiled, each of the files called by the \addchap commands appears to be found. However, an error is returned and, the first file in the list is not found, thus halting the compile. My remedy is to connect each of the words in the file name thus: C001_My_File.tex.

Is it possible to have filenames that contain spaces?

My MWE:-

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,british,twoside,openany,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    \addchap{ONE}
        \input{./blindtex.tex}
    \addchap{TWO}
         \input{./blindtex.tex}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Try with `\input{"C001 My File.tex"}`, but you're better not using spaces in file names.

Comment: Thank you - no this doesn't work. I've tried different combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe package [`grffile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile) helps.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{filecontents*}{"a filename with spaces.tex"}
Do not use spaces in file names.
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\input{"a filename with spaces.tex"}
\end{document}
```